# Partial derivatives in tensor/index notation!

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, tensors, index-notation

For my continuum mechanics class, I'm tasked with finding $\nabla u$, $u$ being $u = b\frac{x}{|x|^3}$. Here, $b$ is a scalar constant.
Attempt at the solution:
I rewrite $\frac{1}{|x|^3}$ as $(x_i^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}}$, in order to express $u$ as a product of two functions. Now I'm at:
\begin{equation}
\nabla u = \frac{\delta}{\delta x_j} bx_i(x_i^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}}
\end{equation}
Applying the product rule then the chain rule, I end up at:
\begin{equation}
b[(x_i^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}}\delta_{ij}+x_i(\frac{-3}{2}(x_i^2)^{\frac{-5}{2}}\frac{\delta}{\delta x_j}(x_i^2)
\end{equation}

And already here I feel like I'm running into issues where I have repeating indices, when I know conceptually and intuitively they should be free. I know what I *want* to do, but I'm obviously not getting the indices to work out. I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way, or if maybe I'm just entirely wrong about how to take the gradient of a vector field. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be in writing $x_i^2$ in your first line. With the summation convention you could write this as $$\frac{x_i}{\left(x_k x_k\right)^{3/2}}.$$ But the expression you have written, $\frac{x_i}{\left(x_i^2\right)^{3/2}}$, uses the same index both for the vector in the numerator and (what should be) the sum leading to a real number in the denominator, which results in the confusion you mentioned that it looks like the $x_i$ in the numerator is being summed over $i$.

Comment: could I write the denominator as $x_k^2$?

Comment: it would just help me with how I've been doing the math so far

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just realized that would cause an issue with free indices

Comment: Using that form you used for the denominator, wouldn't $u_i$ then expand to be $x_i(x_1x_1)^\frac{-3}{2}+x_i(x_2x_2)^\frac{-3}{2}+x_i(x_3x_3)^\frac{-3}{2}$, which is completely different?

Comment: When you write something like what i just did, e.g. f(x_i A_ij x_j), it is intended to mean do the sums BEFORE plugging it in to f. The summation convention is basically a way to represent things like dot products and matrix multiplications, so this is the only order that "makes sense".

Comment: That being said, you could also just write |xl^2, not worry about how to write it with summation convention in the denominator, and just work out d(x^2) / dx_j when you eventually need it

Comment: The problem with writing x_k^2 is that it suggests a single value of k (free index on both sides of equation) that is not summed over.